# PDF reader that zooms to omit left+right (vertical) margins

Tags: android, pdf

When trying to read a PDF on a bigger screen phone, I like to quickly zoom to a level that maximises utilization of my screen real estate, so that I can see biggest font without having to scroll horizentally.
That is to a level that I don't see any of the right or left margins of the page. The app should lock the zoom and horizontal movement when working in this mode. The user can only scroll up/down or jump to a page.

I have seen this working perfectly on default PDF reader on iPhone 6+. I have tested multiple PDF readers:

- Google Drive PDF Reader
- Adobe PDF Reader
- Drive PDF Reader
- Think Free Viewer
- PDF Reader by Ivan Ivanenko (is able to lock horizontally, but not easy to use without auto zooming side)
- QPDF
- RadaeePDF Viewer

I also installed some other popular PDF viewers on the market. None of them had this feature.This seems to be many users' question:http://androidforums.com/threads/why-do-all-android-pdf-readers-suck.269259/

edit: the Reflow function offered by many PDF readers does not work well for books that are not mainly plain text. Also I have found Reflow very slow for my big books

Comment: I think most of the reader won't be having that feature can try with Mobile Document Viewer as said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, [Document Viewer](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.sufficientlysecure.viewer/) is what you are looking for:

- supports PDF, EPUB, DjVu, XPS (OpenXPS), Comic Books (cbz), FictionBook (fb2, fb2.zip)...
- the available settings are huge... (don't know were to start and stop to explain; you have to dig through)
- BUT the one thing you are looking for (since it's not the default behavior) has a "shortcut": open the *menu*, go to *view* and check *cut pages*.
  <sub>(maybe the items are called a little bit different, because I only use the app in german.)</sub>
- btw: also double-tap to zoom (for a obvious area) - like known in browsers  - is supported.

Comment: In the version I installed, that was done with 'Crop Pages (Auto)'. 
It is a bit slower than other PDF readers when opening the 1500p programming book I read, but definitely does what I was after.

Comment: Do you also know of an app with the same feature but for Windows? Thanks.

Comment: @Shayan i have hardly an idea since i don't use Windows, but to me *"`Ctrl + 3` - Fit Content"* in the [docs](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Keyboard-shortcuts) of [**SumatraPDF**](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) sounds a little bit like it. - you'll have to try it.

Answer (score 3):

**Xodo PDF reader** has exactly the feature you are looking for.

Android version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=en

iOS version: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xodo-pdf-pro-highlight-sign-search-take-notes-edit/id805075929?mt=8

After opening the PDF file, on the top menu, click the folded-paper icon, another menu will appear, choose "crop".
You can choose between **automated crop** and **manual crop**. You can also apply manual crop to all pages with just two taps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you need is the pdf "reflow" function. Adobe reader for mobile can do this well for most text only pdfs. You can enable text reflow somewhere in the app's setting menu. But for scanned pdfs and documents with a lot of tables & graphics, KOReader ([ref](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/95989)), although not very stable, is a better choice.

Comment: I should have made it clear in the question that Reflow does not work for me because of the reason you mentioned: the books I read have too many diagrams and charts and code samples

Answer (score 0):

[Librera Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pdf.reader) has an autocrop button.

It's convenient to use in conjunction with the lock button to prevent left/right scrolling.

Tap in the middle of the page to show/hide the menu.

When Wi-Fi or mobile data is on, loud ads play for example after choosing "Close Book".