# PDF viewer for Linux which can trim margins in presentation mode?

Tags: linux, pdf, presentation, pdf-viewer

Is there any PDF viewer for Linux which can trim margins in presentation mode?

Okular can do this in normal mode but not in presentation mode.
qpdfview can zoom in presentation mode but not trim margins.

Comment: Just to confirm: do you mean something like the ["crop pages" functionality in Document Viewer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19711/2545)?